# Find path in graph with two conditions

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have directed graph. Each edge has length and price for passing it. I need to find path with the lowest cost that is shorter than N.
For example graph is:

```
1 -> 2 {length=12, cost=8}
1 -> 2 {length=8, cost=10}
2 -> 3 {length=21, cost=3}
2 -> 3 {length=12, cost=15}
3 -> 4 {length=18, cost=9}
3 -> 4 {length=12, cost=8}
```

And I need to find path from 1 to 3, that is not longer than 45.

Which functions should I use to solve this?

Comment: _...the lowest cost that is shorter than N..._ well a zero length path is shorter than N and has no cost, so you need more constraints than that.